# Query with Median and Group by and where google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, mean, median, google-query-language

I need to get the grouped median

I have grouped data of the form

```
From    type                 Weight
A       person-person        4
A       person-person        3
A       person-organization  11
A       person-person        5
A       person-organization  6
B       person-person        2
B       person-organization  3
B       person-organization  7
C       person-person        5
C       person-person        2
C       person-organization  15
S       person-organization  7
S       person-person        4
S       person-person        3
```

I need to get the Median grouped by col A where Col B = 'person-person'

```
A   value1
B   value2
C   value3
S   value4
```

I can do this for Average with:

```
=QUERY(Connections!A:C,"Select A, Avg(C) where B='person-person' and C is not null group by A",1)
```

I have tried using the `Median` function but I can not get it to group by column A

Google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZPia3LkVg2Pt4YGIH4KtW49G2uElRFcvWLY6LYOQ-Ss/edit?usp=sharing

Is it possible to get the median is this way?

Thanks

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfortunatelly, in Google Sheets the `QUERY` (nor `ARRAYFORMULA`) function does not support median at all.

---

draggable solution:

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER(C:C, A:A=H2))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

it's now possible:

```
=BYROW(H2:H7, LAMBDA(xx, MEDIAN(FILTER(C:C, A:A=xx))))
```

[image]

or even like:

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, B:B="person-person")), LAMBDA(xx, MEDIAN(FILTER(C:C, A:A=xx))))
```

[image]